# How do you hide option to switch to classic

Tags: lightning-experience

I am trying to make a few users to be lightning users only and not having option to access classic interface.

I have checked "Hide Option to Switch to Salesforce Classic permission" on the profile as mentioned on the link below, and we still see that the user has the option to switch back to classic(in Chrome).

[Make Lightning Experience the Only Experience for Some Users](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_enable_users_disable_switcher.htm)

[image: Hide Option to Switch to Salesforce Classic permission in profiles and permission sets]

Can the switcher be turned off? If so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Users with the system administrator profile or assigned one of the following permissions see the Switch to Salesforce Classic link even when the Hide Option to Switch to Salesforce Classic permission is enabled: Customize Application, Modify All Data, or Manage Users.